# cooks.distance returning more values than there are in my dataset

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, data-mining, lm

I understand how you can get fewer values by having in the dataset. But here is a repeatable example where `cooks.distance` is returning more. I have absolutely no idea how this is possible unless my version of R is completely broken.

Consider

```
library (MASS)
lm.Boston<-lm(medv~crim+indus+age+tax,data=Boston)
cooks.distance(lm.Boston)
nrow(Boston) ## cooks.distance returns 506 values as expected which matches the obs in the dataset.
newBoston<-Boston[Boston$age>50,] ## Now arbitrarily remove some rows.  The number of records is now 359
lm.newBoston<-lm(medv~crim+indus+age+tax,data=newBoston)
cooks.distance(lm.newBoston) ## cooks.distance still returns 506 values.  It seems to be "Stuck" on the previous dataset
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, set

```
CD <- cooks.distance(lm.Boston)
CDnew <- cooks.distance(lm.newBoston)
```

Don't be fooled by the "names" field of the vector. Check `length(CD)` and `length(CDnew)` instead.

You can extract the "names" attributes by `names(CD)` and `names(CDnew)`. They are consistent with `row.names(Boston)` and `row.names(newBoston)`, respectively.

Not just `cooks.distance` has this behavior; other generic functions like `predict`, `residuals`, `rstandard`, `fitted` and `fitted.values` are the same.

Comment: Wow - that was embarrassing.  The only thing more embarrassing is that I would have spent DAYS trying to reconcile this.  Thanks for the lightning fast result.  You rock!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to return equal numbers below:

```
library (MASS)

# Case - 1
lm.Boston<-lm(medv~crim+indus+age+tax,data=Boston)
nrow(Boston)
length(cooks.distance(lm.Boston))
```

[image]

```
# Case - 2
newBoston<-Boston[Boston$age>50,] 
lm.newBoston<-lm(medv~crim+indus+age+tax,data=newBoston)
nrow(newBoston)
length(cooks.distance(lm.newBoston))
```

[image]